# AWS Route53 A-record pointing to classic load balancer (created by Kubernetes) works with http but not https

Tags: kubernetes, dns, load-balancing, amazon-route53, amazon-elb

My load balancer has been created by `kubectl apply -f loadbalancer.yaml`

```
> cat loadbalancer.yaml
kind: Service
apiVersion: v1
metadata:
  name: leafsheets-django-service-staging
  namespace: $K8S_NAMESPACE
  # annotations:
  #   # Note that the backend talks over HTTP.
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-backend-protocol: http
  #   # TODO: Fill in with the ARN of your certificate.
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-cert: arn:aws:acm:us-east-1:795730031374:certificate/7a488844-4fea-4214-8a72-748f5f09f19c
  #   # Only run SSL on the port named "https" below.
  #   service.beta.kubernetes.io/aws-load-balancer-ssl-ports: "https"
spec:
  selector:
    pod: $K8S_POD
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    name: http
    port: 80
    targetPort: 8000
  - protocol: TCP
    name: https
    port: 443
    targetPort: 8000
  type: LoadBalancer
```

I've created a DNS record in Route53 pointing to it.

Pointing chrome to http://mysubdomain.mydomain.com fetches a JSON blob, but https times out.

I've checked my certificate, and it is valid and covers *.mydomain.com.

I've verified the load balancer allows inbound traffic on 443.

What could be wrong?

The comments in the .yaml file were written by a previous developer, and I don't understand them. Is the answer in these comments?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the TCP record for HTTPS associated with the load balancer and creating instead a SSL record (with the cert.) fixes.

[image: ssl-record]